# ASP MVC Session crashes on device network change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I don´t know how to address this issue to find its source, but I have developed an ASP MVC website using ASP Identity Cookie Authentication, but when I tested it on mobile devices, if I change network state, let's say switch from 4G to WiFi or change Wi-Fi networks I present errors on the website that I have identified are related with User Claim functions or UserId related operations. What could be triggering this errors?

Comment: so what are the errors?

Comment: @trailmax Usually errors of object reference to null, like for example if I obtain a user claim and store it on a variable it later indicates that such variable is null or not defined. Such errors only happen on network change

Comment: Claims are stored in auth cookie. If claims are lost, means cookie is lost too. But that will mean that user is not authenticated anymore. Cookie truncation can happen when connection is going through a proxy and proxy cuts off cookies - I've not seen this in practice, but this is possible.

Comment: `variable is null or not defined` - are you talking about JS variable? Samples of code where you see the problem will help. Otherwise we are guessing here... and all we know is that magic pixies sprinkled some magic dust on your variables and they disappear.